# Dual Boot:Grub is not working properly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I bought a Lenovo Ideapad 330, so I added a SSD to make a dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu. I transferred Windows to my SSD using MiniTool Partition Wizard, then I used a USB Boot to install Ubuntu 18.04, when I first tried, the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10" didn't show up. So I runned Windows and made a partition for Linux, decreasing the windows partition on my ssd, after doing that, I tried again to install Ubuntu, but the option to install alongside Windows still didn't showed up. Again, I runned Windows, cleaned up and removed the partition I created and then I just decreased 30GB from Windows partition and I let it "unallocated", in the Ubuntu setup I created the partition and installed Ubuntu in this partition, also created a swap partition in my HD (2GB, i thought that was enough for my 8GB laptop) and created a boot partition with 10MB as the Ubuntu setup recommended. My real problem is: Grub is not showing up, when I go into BIOS and select "UEFI" for boot mode, it boots directly to Windows and when I select "Legacy Support", it boots directly to Ubuntu. Another detail: following instructions I found here, I created a option "Windows 10 (UEFI)" in Grub, so when I boot Ubuntu and press shift or esc (I dont remember the exact key), the Grub shows up and the option I created is there, but it dont work, if I select that, it just come back to Grub selection.

EDIT:
I booted Ubuntu by setting Legacy First in BIOS, then runned 'sudo parted -l' in terminal. (I can't get the USB Live right now). Here is the output:

```
Model: ATA WDC WDS240G2G0A- (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  350MB  349MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      350MB   367MB  16,8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      367MB   208GB  207GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      208GB   239GB  30,7GB  ext4
 5      239GB   239GB  10,5MB                                             bios_grub


Model: ATA WDC WD10SPZX-24Z (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Warning: failed to translate partition name
Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB   273MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      274MB   290MB   16,8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   945GB   945GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      997GB   999GB   2000MB  linux-swap(v1)
 4      999GB   1000GB  1049MB  ntfs                                          hidden, diag
```

Comment: Need to look at partition details of SSD. Boot up from USB Live. Run command `sudo parted -l` and post up the output.

Comment: @PaulBenson done, I edited the original post with the output..

Comment: Delete what you just added. Run command again. Edit your answer by highlighting all the output from the terminal with your mouse, then copy it - Ctrl+Shft+C. Paste output into question from a **new line**, then highlight with mouse, and click on the double braces ( curly brackets {} ). I might be able to read this then.

Comment: @PaulBenson it's done

Comment: The bios_grub is used for grub install in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode on gpt partitioned drives. UEFI & BIOS boot are not compatible, you can only dual boot from UEFI boot menu as you are. You can easily convert install to UEFI boot, using Boot-Repair and Ubuntu live installer booted in UEFI mode. Use advanced mode to totally reinstall the UEFI version of grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  If still issues post link to summary report it creates.

Comment: That's better. 1) you must have your laptop set to UEFI, not Legacy BIOS as your disks are formatted to GPT and Windows will only run from that. 2) Which **disk and  partition** is Windows installed on? Looks like you've tried to install Windows on both disks as MRP is present on both. 3) You'll need a Live Ubuntu USB, so make one (from Windows) then come back. If you have a problem makng one, just ask.

Comment: Well, I solved my problem by booting from USB-Live Ubuntu on UEFI mode and opted for "Try Ubuntu" then running boot-repair. But now, as @PaulBenson said, i have MRP present on both, on my HD and SSD, but Windows is just installed on SSD actually. How do I remove MRP and Windows boot manager from my HD?

Comment: You should be able to delete partition **sdb2**, MRP without an issue. You can also delete **sda5**, bios,_grub. You've probably now got several entries in Grub for Windows. You only actually need one, so let us know if you want to tidy up.

Comment: Yes, now I've got several entries in Grub for Windows, 6, actually. I know which one is the actual Windows I want to access and I removed the others through Grub-customizer. But I know that's not the best move to do that. Can I remove the partitions through Windows diskpart? Or there is a better solution?